# How to cross-platform port unix pipes?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, gtk, pipe, unix

I have a code that looks like this:

uses this library

```
#include <unistd.h>

#define READ_FD 0
#define WRITE_FD 1

int m_pipe[2]; 

if(pipe(m_pipe) != -1) {
   unsigned long Id = gdk_input_add(m_pipe[READ_FD], GDK_INPUT_READ, Callback, (gpointer)this);
}
```

and it surprisingly builds on both linux(all major flavors: AS3, AS5, solaris) and windows. However, it doesn't really work on windows at all.

How should a code using pipes be implemented so it works on both windows and linux?

Comment: what does mean "it doesn't really works on windows at all"? please attach an error message etc

Comment: Ugh, I can really attach it as it compiles and runs,  but gtk gives some sort of a hashing message when it reads from the pipe on windows.

Comment: "Some sort of a hashing message"? Don't make us keep guessing. Tell us the read message, and the real return value indicating error. Also, that's not even a valid call to `pipe`. Copy and paste the code that's really failing.

Comment: that is a real code posix use of pipes... sorry, but I dont have an error message. All I want is to see how none-named piped are used in windows, and I will provide a different implementation for each platform...

Comment: No, it's not real code. The `pipe` function takes an *array* of ints, not just one. If that line of your code isn't real, why should we think any of the rest of it is? And if you don't have an error message, then what was the "hashing message" you said GTK gives you?

Comment: Agh, I m_pipes is array of ints, if you look closely in the code,  you can see that I use it as an array... just copied wrong...

Comment: Rob I just need an exampoe of using a non-named pipes in windows, and I will take it from there...

Comment: A more specific question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190184/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-in-windows-api-and-pass-to-gtk-function

Answer (score 0):

I would expose the upper functionality and not pipes themselves. On unix the lower level library code would use pipes but on some other machine it could use a different mechanism.