# How to use anonymous pipes in windows api (and pass to gtk function)?

Tags: c++, gtk, pipe, windows

I need to be able to pass int value  representing fd (pipe fd) to [gtk](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/unstable/gdk-Input.html#gdk-input-add) function as a first parameter

```
gint gdk_input_add gint source,
         GdkInputCondition condition,
         GdkInputFunction function,
                       gpointer data);
```

How do I do that, as [CreatePipe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813414) returns HANDLE which is NOT int?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a `HANDLE` value to a C file descriptor, call [`_open_osfhandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts1c9x.aspx).